# String attribute to numeric in WEKA

Tags: type-conversion, attributes, weka

I am new to weka and trying to analyse a dataset.

I imported a csv into the explorer window and noticed that one column from the csv file that contains numeric values as percentages (e.g. 46%) has been imported as nominal.

[image]

How can I transform these values from nominal to numerical?

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way would be:

- open the CSV file in a text editor
- remove all the `%`
- re-import the CSV file in Weka

Other tools, like the *Spreadsheet file viewer* or the *Flow editor* in [ADAMS](https://adams.cms.waikato.ac.nz/), allow you that kind of conversion on the fly using the `SpreadSheetConvertCells` transformer:

- **finder**: define the correct column range to operate on
- **conversion**: `adams.data.conversion.StringExpression -expression "substitute(X, \\\"%\\\", \\\"\\\")"`